# Converting Fractional part from Decimal to Binary

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am reading a book on [Discrete Mathematics.](https://books.google.com/books?id=-MMcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22Expressed+another+way,+the+halves+bit+is+0+because%22&source=bl&ots=xcpQLQA-O1&sig=ACfU3U2hvtJ2qe12G266hDN8P4GsLk1OJQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Expressed%20another%20way%2C%20the%20halves%20bit%20is%200%20because%22&f=false)

In the section **Converting Decimal to Binary number** author states the following:

> We now turn to the problem of converting a decimal fraction to binary.
>   For example, suppose we want to find the binary representation of
>   $0.375_{10}$. Because $0.375$ is less than $0.5$, the first bit to the right of the point
>   in the binary representation (the halves bit, which has a place value of 
>   $\frac 1 2$)
>   will be $0$.
>
> Expressed another way, the halves bit is $0$ because $2 × 0.375$ is
>   less than $1$. If, on the other hand, we had started with a number greater
>   than or equal to $\frac 1 2$, say $0.875$, the halves bit would be $1$, and $2*0875 >= 1$.

My question from where does $2 × 0.375$ jump into the scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N=0.375$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that the halves bit is 1.  This means that the number of interest, $N$, is greater than 0.5, which implies that

$N > 0.5 \Rightarrow 2 N > 1$

which is a contradiction as $2 \times 0.375 < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The fractional representation of $0.375_{10}$ is $\frac 3 8$; since $\frac 3 8 < \frac 1 2 \ ( = 2^{-1})$, the halves bit will be $0$.  In that same vein, $\frac 3 8 > \frac 1 4 
\ (=2^{-2})$, so $1$ will be in the quarters bit; subtracting $\frac 3 8$ and $\frac 1 4$ gives us $\frac 1 8$, meaning there's a $1$ in the eighths bit ($=2^{-3}$).

Hence

> $${0.375_{10} = 0.011_{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

How do we find the decimal expansion of a number? One way is to repeatedly multiply by $10$, and then remove the integer part. Take $x=\frac38$ for example: $\frac38\times10=\frac{30}{8}=3+\frac34$. Since $10x$ is between $3$ and $4$, we know that $x$ is between $.3$ and $.4$, i.e., its first decimal digit is $3$.

To get the next decimal digit, we get rid of the $3$, and look at the remaining fractional part: $\frac34$. Multiplying again by the base $10$, we get $\frac34\times 10=\frac{30}{4}=7+\frac12$. Thus, the next decimal digit is $7$.

Finally, multiplying the remaining fraction, $\frac12$ by $10$, we get precisely $5$, so we have a terminating decimal expansion: $0.375$

---

Any other base works exactly the same way: We can write $\frac38$ in base $6$, by repeatedly multiplying by $6$:

$\frac38\times 6 = 2+\frac14\\
\frac14\times 6 = 1+\frac12\\
\frac12\times 6 = 3,$

so apparently, $\frac38=.213_6$, which we can verify by reading it as a fraction with denominator $6^3$:

$.213_6=\frac{213_6}{6^3} = \frac{2\cdot 36+1\cdot 6+ 3\cdot 1}{216}=\frac{81}{216}=\frac38$

Similarly when the base is $2$:

$\frac38\times 2 = 0+\frac34\\
\frac34\times2=1+\frac12\\
\frac12\times 2 = 1.$

Thus, the binary expansion of $\frac38$ is $.011_2$.

---

In short, we can move the dot one place to the right by multiplying by our base. Doing so is a good way to reveal the expansion, one digit at a time.